# SherlockActionBar semi transparent

Tags: android, transparency, actionbarsherlock

is it possible to make the SherlockActionBar semi-transparent, without assigning it a background drawable?

Comment: Why can you not give it a background drawable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);` this make it simi-transparent, but its a floating ActionBar, the content can be behind it.